# How to decrease latency for HIVE data ingestion in Apache Flink?

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am directly writing data to HDFS files in orc format using Apache Flink for HIVE tale to read. Apache Flink will convert in progress file to finish state after checkpoint time. Only finished files are visible to the HIVE table. So the latency will be checkpoint time(in my case it is 10 mins). If we decrease checkpoint time to decrease latency, then Flink creates too many HDFS files. So how to decrease latency while not creating too many files?

Comment: If I understood correctly this is a trade-off between the time to create a checkpoint and the number of files it creates. It is very domain specific, but maybe you can configure `StreamExecutionEnvironment.getCheckpointConfig().setMinPauseBetweenCheckpoints(milliseconds)` like it is explained here: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/state/large_state_tuning.html#tuning-checkpointing

Comment: or maybe decide to use few checkpoints, that will lead to large files, and then use compression https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/state/large_state_tuning.html#compression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing you can do is to reduce the parallelism.

Comment: What do you mean by modifying the rolling policy? Bulk Formats can only have `OnCheckpointRollingPolicy`, which rolls (ONLY) on every checkpoint.
https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/connectors/streamfile_sink.html#bulk-encoded-formats

Comment: `StreamExecutionEnvironment.getCheckpointConfig().setMinPauseBetweenCheckpoints(milliseconds)` will this work?

Comment: setMinPauseBetweenCheckpoints is useful in cases where checkpointing is taking a long time to complete, and you want Flink to be able to spend time running without checkpointing being ongoing. In your case I don't see how it would help.